# How to read the component path field using parameter schema in c#

Tags: schema, c#

I want to read the component path using parameter schema and want to assign that parameter schema to the tbb.

Comment: What is your question? I guess, you should go through the below link first: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask                    http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is very unclear, could you please edit it and attempt to clarify what you exactly want to do? Perhaps it is good to start with supplying a bit of context. Explain in general what your requirements are, what you have done so far or what your planned solution is roughly, and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Indeed - this question needs some improvement before anyone will be able to answer it. What exactly are you trying to do?